# PI 2 + .net - missing coreclr.dll

Tags: windows-iot, setup, arm

My first time trying to get a PI working... Neat idea, pulling out my hair though.

No matter what project I build [simple or not], when deploying I get the missing coreclr.dll. What SDK am I missing? Any help is much appreciated. Once I get the environment set up I want to introduce my son to this stuff.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   DEP6701 : Bootstrapping failed with unexpected error: 'DEP6960 : 
Source file does not exist: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Phone Tools\12.0\Debugger\target\armv4i\coreclr.dll'.  HelloWorld(LCD)
```

Comment: I haven't had this one and my google fu is letting me down. Were you working to a particular tutorial or set of instructions when you a) installed everything and b) created your projects and, if so, could you add suitable links to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it - it was a botched install of the windows 10 sdk.  My computer died a couple hours into the install (took 5+ hours!) and I didn't realize it.  Upon boot up it thought it had installed.  Uninstall + install fixed it.

Comment: We are glad you managed to solve the problem and answer your question. You should have enough rep to mark this answer as accepted too now. PS 5 Hours is way too long? But glad it got sorted.

Comment: I guess my idea of install time is just unrealistic :)  Thank you for the reminder on this - I do indeed have the ability to mark it.

Comment: Thanks. No I actually meant 5 hours is toooooo long ! :) it should be 10, 20 minutes tops. That's strange. Maybe longer if it's downloading and installing